# Object Not Passing in NavigationController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am having an issue that's really confusing me.  I am converting a project from Objective-C to Swift and am using storyboards for the first time.  The app downloads RSS data and stores the title, link and pubDate in an Article object in CoreData.  When the user clicks a row it loads the article in a webView.

The issue I am having has to do with passing the Article object to the the webView.  I am able to pass it with a button placed on a tableViewCell but selecting the cell causes the app to crash and it says that the Article Object passed to the webView is nil.  However if I test it before passing it with a println(), it shows that it is not nil.

Here is the code I am using for the button placed on the cell.

```
@IBAction func article(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        // Pulling the most recent story to display on the HomeViewController
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Article")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "feed == 'FLO Cycling' OR feed == 'Triathlete' OR feed == 'Velo News' OR feed == 'Cycling News' OR feed == 'Ironman'")
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "pubDate", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        
        // Set up NSError for the Fetch
        var fetchError : NSError?
        // When you perform a fetch the returned object is an array of the Atricle Entities.
        let fetchedObjects = self.articleContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &fetchError) as! [Article]
        
        //Grab the latest Article and place the title in the label in the HomeViewController
        self.latestArticle = fetchedObjects.last
        
        // Grab the latestArticleViewController so it can be presented modally.  Make sure you set up the storyboard identifier.
        self.articleView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ArticleViewController") as? ArticleViewController
        self.articleView!.currentArticle = self.latestArticle
        self.articleView!.articleContext = self.articleContext
        self.presentViewController(self.articleView!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Here is the code I am using for the didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let selectedArticle = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Article
    self.articleView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ArticleViewController") as? ArticleViewController
    self.articleView!.currentArticle = selectedArticle
    self.articleView!.articleContext = self.articleContext
    println("This is coming from didSelectRowAtIndexPath \(self.articleView!.currentArticle!.link)")

    self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.articleView!, animated: true)

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Here is a picture of the app with the button on the cell.

[image]

This is what happens when I tap the button.

[image]

Here is the output I get from the console when I touch the cell.  You can see the println() shows the Article has a link.

> This is coming from didSelectRowAtIndexPath http://flocycling.blogspot.com/2015/05/order-20-of-details-its-hard-to-believe.html
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is a screen shot of the line the app crashes on.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Current Article Declaration and Initialization**

currentArticle is declared in ArticleViewController in the following way.

```
    class ArticleViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
    // Properties
    var currentArticle : Article?
}
```

As for the initialization in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method I do the following to initialize the value the ArticleViewController that I load.

```
    let selectedArticle = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Article
self.articleView!.currentArticle = selectedArticle
```

Which is equivalent to what I do when I tap the button with the following.  Or at least I think it's the same.

```
self.latestArticle = fetchedObjects.last
self.articleView!.currentArticle = self.latestArticle
```

**Two Errors Thrown**

> 2015-05-31 18:42:38.227 FLOCycling1.1.1[98389:6596654] CoreData:
> error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class
> 'FLOCycling1_1_1.Article'  2015-05-31 18:42:38.227
> FLOCycling1.1.1[98389:6596654] -[FLOCycling1_1_1.Article link]:
> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f81ead7f940

Take care,

Jon

Comment: can you show us hoe you declare and initialize currentArticle?

Comment: I added the code to the end.  If you want to see anything else please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your var currentArticle  is not initialized by the time you are calling it, I see in your pic you're already did some lazy initialization in your code, repete for this variable and all should start work fine, I append a example below:

```
lazy var currentArticle: Article = {
    let article = Article()
    //any other initialization you need
    return article
}()
```

I hope that help you!

Comment: I gave this a try and two errors were thrown.  You can see them at the end of the post above.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: It seems that your Article class depend in other variables to be initialized as well. I would recommend that you create a new variable as a string to save the value you are passing and use the string to initialize your Article the old way you was doing. Let me know if it work

Answer (score 0):

I have no understanding of why this fixed the problem but I will explain what I did.  Maybe someone with more experience with Storyboards can explain.

I used several viewControllers for each feed that the RSS parser sorts.  Since all articles are displayed in the same format I used one ArticleViewController to display the articles.  The image below shows my overall hierarchy for the storyboard.  The VC on the far right is the ArticleViewController and the seven that are to the left of it are the VC's for the RSS feeds.

[image]

I created a segue for each RSS feed to lead to the ArticleViewController.  Each had a unique name that I could use in prepareForSegue.  You can see the segues in the zoomed view below.

[image]

Originally I tried to use the prepareForSegue method with the following code to pass the Article Object to the ArticleViewController.

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
       if segue.identifier == "floArticleSegue"
       {
           if let indexPath = self.storyTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()            {
               let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Article

               (segue.destinationViewController as! ArticleViewController).currentArticle = object
           }
       }
}
```

When I did this the object did not get passed to the Article ViewController.  I then tried the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and the same problem occurred.  I've repeated that error here for clarity.

> This is coming from didSelectRowAtIndexPath http://flocycling.blogspot.com/2015/05/order-20-of-details-its-hard-to-believe.html fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

To fix the problem I deleted the segue from the RSS feed VC's to the ArticleViewController and used the same code I used previously.  This code is as follows.

```
let selectedArticle = self.fetchedResultsController!.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Article
self.articleView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ArticleViewController") as? ArticleViewController
self.articleView!.currentArticle = selectedArticle
self.articleView!.articleContext = self.articleContext
println("This is coming from didSelectRowAtIndexPath \(self.articleView!.currentArticle!.link)")

self.navigationController!.pushViewController(self.articleView!, animated: true)

tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
```

For whatever reason, when the segue was deleted from the storyboard the object is passed and the app works without any issues.  I hope this helps someone else and maybe someone can explain why.

Take care,

Jon